# How in python to run some small part of the code in the tor network (Windows)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tor

I have python code with a module that parses data, and I need the part where it parses data was on the tor network.

Comment: So do you want to host a server via Tor? What do you mean by "running code in Tor"?

Comment: I want a part of my code to be in the tor network, that is, to make a function that changes the ip address in small a piece of code when called.

Comment: The IP address of _what_? Your computer? So you want to connect to Tor with Python? Also, I don't really understand what "the ip address in small a piece of code" means...

Comment: I need the code, for example:

`os.system(ipconfig)`

It is performed via the tor network and changed its ip every time it was started.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to "perform code via the Tor network". You run code on some computer, or on a network of computers, but you'll need to have access to these computers to do that. For example, you can't run code on my computer, and I can't on yours. If you want to change the external IP of your computer, route its traffic through Tor. But that has nothing to do with Python.